# Как скриптом взять текст в одном span и вставить в другой в место текста который в нем?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как с помощью скрипта взять текст из одного тега `span` и вставить в `span` с другим классом (с предварительной очисткой `span`, в который добавляется текст)?

Как сейчас:

```
<div class="block1"><span class="ctm">Холодильник Bosch</span></div>
<div class="block2"><span class="mprice">Произвольный текст</span></div>
```

Как нужно:

```
<div class="block1"><span class="ctm">Холодильник Bosch</span></div> 
<div class="block2"><span class="mprice">Холодильник Bosch</span></div>
```

Значение в `span` с классом `.ctm` изначально неизвестно (на всех страницах по разному).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как должен выглядеть готовый скрипт?

Comment: А эти `span`'ы  выделены отделными контейнерами-родителями?

Comment: да у каждого span есть отдельный div родитель

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно сначала определить общего родителя, например, через `.closest()`, а потом внутри родителя найти нужный `span` через `.find()`:

```js
$('span.ctm').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).closest('.block').find('span.mprice').text(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block">
  <span class="ctm">Холодильник Bosch</span><br />
  <span class="mprice">Произвольный текст</span><br /><br />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="ctm">Холодильник Philips</span><br />
  <span class="mprice">Произвольный текст</span><br /><br />
</div>
<div class="block">
  <span class="ctm">Холодильник LG</span><br />
  <span class="mprice">Произвольный текст</span><br /><br />
</div>
```

Comment: я в вопросе уточнил конструкцию, подскажите пожалуйста как с учетом исправленной конструкции должен выглядеть скрипт?

Comment: @Slava а что это за теги такои div1 и div2?)

Comment: Да тороплюсь-запарился )) исправил

Comment: @Slava судя по вашей структуре, можете вместо '.block' использовать просто 'div'. Но я все же советую вам добавить общий класс для этого блока и делать выборку именно по этому классу, чтобы после изменений структуры этих блоков у вас все не поломалось

Comment: Отлично, то что нужно! Предложенный скрипт подставляет из span - источника текст во все перечисленные в скрипте span 'ы на всей странице. Хорошо, что дали пояснения к скрипту как он работет, для меня это важно!)  Большое спасибо!